# In Python, when a function doesn't need an object prefix?

Tags: python, class, function, object, methods

In `sorted(list(mydict.keys()))`, `sorted` and `list` doesn't need an object prefix `someobject.`, but `keys()` needed `dict1.`.  When, or for what functions, is the prefix necessary?

Comment: You should think the other way around. Are objects that need `.something()` to call their methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Methods* need to be called on a specific object. *Functions* don't.

The functions that are available at any time are the built-in ones, such as `sorted` and `list`, plus any functions that are in modules that you've imported or that you've defined yourself. The methods that are available on a particular object are the ones that are defined on that object's type.

Comment: Do the built-in functions have their "implicit" objects?

Comment: No, actually, it's the other way around. All methods are really functions, and the object which the method is called on is implicitly passed as the first parameter. `mydict.keys()` is syntactic sugar for `dict.keys(mydict)`.

Answer (score 2):

The "prefix" means that you are calling a method from an object (someobject or dict in your example). If your function is not a method of an object, you do not need "a prefix"